# WSO2 Enterprise Integrator Unable to call deployed API

Tags: json, xml, rest, api, wso2-esb

I am completely new to WSO2 and I am facing the problem described below.

After deploying the API (composite application *.car file) I am unable to invoke the services of the defined endpoints from WSO2 ESB.

The REST API I am trying to invoke is found deployed on a local tomcat installation, and is located at:

```
http://localhost:8080/CustomerInfoRestService/customers/
```

To retrieve a json customer object I would simply add the customer id, like so:

```
http://localhost:8080/CustomerInfoRestService/customers/2
```

All the services operations (Get, POST, PUT, DELETE) are tested and invoked successfully. For testing I used the tool 'PostMan'.

I created an ESB project using the WSO2 Integration Studio.

First I defined an endpoint with a URI Template of:
http://localhost:8080/CustomerInfoRestService/customers/{uri.var.custId}

Then I defined a REST API. The properties of the API Resource are as follows:

```
URL-Style: URI_Template

URI-Template: /customers/{custId}

Methods: GET
```

In the In-Sequence I added a log mediator, having:

```
Log Category: INFO
Log Level: CUSTOM
```

and I defined its message as:

```
Property Name: message
Property value type: LITERAL
Property Value: Welcome to Customer Service
```

Directly next to the log mediator is a 'Send' mediator, and I included the defined endpoint above.

Then I deploy the composite application as: right-click -> Export Composite Application Project.

I include both the API and and the endpoint in the generated *.car file.

Now to invoke an API request, I call the service using 'curl':

```
curl -v http://localhost:8280/CustomerInfoRestService/customers/2
```

and I get the response:

```
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8280 (#0)
> GET /CustomerInfoRestService/customers/2 HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8280
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Date: Thu, 13 Jun 2019 10:09:06 GMT
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

It seems not to be found (404 error)

I followed the WSO2 documentation, specifically the integration tutorial "Sending a Simple Message to a Service" to create this project, for reference  it is found at:https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Sending+a+Simple+Message+to+a+Service

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Kind Regards,

Comment: What is the context of your API? Is it '/CustomerInfoRestService'? And is there a version type for your API? Like context or url?

Comment: Apologies for not mentioning this information earlier. The api name is "CustomerInfoAPI", context is "/CustomerInfoRestService", version type "none"

Comment: The steps you've followed seems fine. But let's verify if the 404 is thrown by EI or the tomcat Rest API, by enabling wirelogs - https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Debugging+Mediation#DebuggingMediation-Viewingwirelogs If it's the EI, please share your API and the endpoint config (after removing any sensitive information).

Comment: Thank you for your support. Actually I have testing the tomcat Rest API (through the chrome tool 'Postman' and each of the endpoints seem to be operational and giving out successful output. I will enable the wire logs as suggested and get back with the results

Answer (score 0):

This kind of response comes when the API is not deployed or active in the ESB. Did you deploy the car file you created? You did not mention that in your steps. Please make sure that you are able to see the API in the management console (Home -> Service Bus -> API).

Comment: Hi Arunan. I have checked the EI admin console as suggested and the API is successfully deployed, with an invocation URL specified as: http://192.168.0.192/customerService:8280. There are options such as enable tracing and enable statistics. Would it help to troubleshoot using these features? thank you in advance for your support

Comment: The URL you have mentioned here says 192.168.0.192/customerService:8280. But you are trying to invoke http://localhost:8280/CustomerInfoRestService/{resource-path}. Is that correct?